# jquery click function not working with an if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(function() {
  var passInput = document.getElementById("pass").value;
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    if (passInput === 1234) {
      alert("Correct");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="passwordEntryDiv">
  <input id="pass" type="password">
  <button id="btn">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Why isn't this working? this isn't for a website or anything just something I'm doing

Comment: Don't you need to set passInput within the click function? Otherwise won't it run on page load and the value will be empty all the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `passInput` is only being set set once, when the code is ran -- it will never update in the code you've provided.  When the user clicks the button, it is comparing that original value to `1234`, not the current value in the text box.  Put it inside your click handler to get a new value every time the click happens.

```
$(function () {
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    var passInput = document.getElementById("pass").value;
    if (passInput === 1234) {
      alert("Correct");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple, you are storing the value of the input on page load. That variable will not update as user enters data. So it never changes from being an empty string.

Now access the value inside the button click instead and you have updated value to validate

```
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    /* get value when click occurs*/
    var passInput = 1*$("#pass").val();
    if (passInput === 1234) {
      alert("Correct");
    }
  });
```

Also values are strings so if testing against a number you need to convert string to number. Lots of ways to convert to number.

Answer (score -1):

It's an input field so the value would be "1234" not 1234.

Change:
`passInput === 1234`

To:
`passInput === "1234"`

Also, place the value inside of the click event.

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
    if ($("#pass").val() === "1234") {
        alert("Correct");
});
```